# Nested Table + GetElement in C-compiled function crashes kernel

Tags: bugs, compile

#### Bug introduced in 8.0. [CASE:4075198]

---

Using a nested `Table` and then `` Compile`GetElement `` crashes my kernel when I run a function compiled to C. Here's a MWE:

```
wowC =
 Compile[
  {},
  Module[
   {mat},
   mat =
    Table[
     Table[1, {j, 5}],
     {i, 5}
     ];
   Compile`GetElement[mat, 1, 1]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
wowC[]
```

Calling that *will* crash your kernel so do it in one you don't care about.

Note that this isn't an issue without `CompilationTarget -> "C"` or the nested `Table` or using `GetElement`.

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 9):

This really gives me headaches. I am not completely sure, but I guess that it is about a badly initialized pointer. In this case, this would be a bug (imho).

So, this is my current explanation for the behavior:

Here is the initialization code for our library function behind `wowC`. The important part is `I0_8 = (mint) -1;`

```
DLLEXPORT int Initialize_m00000849811(WolframLibraryData libData)
{
if( initialize)
{
funStructCompile = libData->compileLibraryFunctions;
I0_6 = (mint) 0;
I0_0 = (mint) 5;
I0_8 = (mint) -1;
I0_2 = (mint) 1;
initialize = 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

In the beginning of the main function, we find

```
I0_1 = I0_0;
I0_5 = I0_8;
dims[0] = I0_1;
dims[1] = I0_5;
err = funStructCompile->MTensor_allocate(T0_1, 2, 2, dims);
if( err)
{
goto error_label;
}
P0 = MTensor_getIntegerDataMacro(*T0_1);
D0 = MTensor_getDimensionsMacro(*T0_1);
```

So, `T0_1` is initialized as tensor with dimensions $5 \times (-1)$! For a usual `MTensor`, `P0 = MTensor_getIntegerDataMacro(*T0_1);` sets the pointer `P0` onto the first position of the data field of `T0_1` (MTensors are actually flat (1-dimensional) lists of values along with information about the dimensions of the tensor, and maybe some pointers, 
e.g. to first elements of each row or higher dimensional slice.) Since the data field is empty, `P0` will be quite likely point to `NULL` or some other memory position that we don't know. Afterwards, `T0_1` gets extended by more and more rows by several calls of the form

```
err = funStructCompile->MTensor_insertMTensor(*T0_1, *T0_2, &I0_5);
```

*But the pointer `P0` gets never updated.* So in the end, when the result is about to be retrieved with

```
{
mint S0 = I0_2 - 1;
S0 = S0 * D0[1] + (I0_2 - 1);
I0_5 = P0[S0];
}
*Res = I0_5;
```

this has to cause issues, either due to illegal memory access or due to dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Man, I am happy that I don't have to work with C/C++ on an every day basis!

Comment: I'm impressed. I was looking at the C code but I didn't have the time to properly deconstruct it. Any suggestions on how to work around this in general? (Other than by the obvious using `[[ . ]]` with these nested `Table` expressions)

Comment: I would use `mat = Table[Table[1, {j, 5}], {i, 5}];` for initialization. This has the advantage that it also avoids these calls to `funStructCompile->MTensor_insertMTensor` which should involve a copy operation. Using ``Compile`GetElement[Compile`GetElement[mat, 1], 1]`` does also work, though.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the nested `Table` in a much more complicated case where I can't simply do that. How will the second perform relative to `[[ . ]]`?

Comment: That's a good question! I am afraid that ``Compile`GetElement[mat, 1]`` will copy the whole first row so that it might actually be slower than using `Part`. But I'm not sure. I guess you have to give both a try. I am also curious how it performs but I have no time to test it at the moment.

Comment: _Man, I am happy that I don't have to work with C/C++ on an every day basis!_ I hope you do realise that C code like this is not at all representative of C code that people actually maintain and like to work with. Working with C/C++ on a daily basis can be a lot of fun, but working with automatically generated code on a daily basis (in any language that is not assembly language from a good optimising compiler) is hell.

Comment: @tomsmeding You have a point. Or let's say, a half one. ;)