# Long Execution Time of Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, system-performance

I have a set of linear homogeneous equations with 8580 variables. I want to estimate the time `Mathematica` takes to solve the system, by solving smaller sets of equations. For example, I can take three equations, apply `Reduce` and see the `AbsoluteTiming`. Then, I repeat the same thing with four, five, ten etc.. equations and I can fit the execution time of `Reduce` with a polynomial or exponential function.

However, the system is very big, only three equations store about 2MB in a text-file and indeed `Reduce` takes too much time when applied to only one equation (which instead should be very easy, since it should just resolve on one unknown ). Instead, `Solve` is pretty fast but I have some experiences that `Solve` does not find all the solutions, so I would like to rely on the algorithms used by `Reduce`. For example, you can find one equation [here](https://privatebin.net/?60031033c3bd109d#5edCMcmQUK9qWXVyFu3su7Y22zsGsGme2orcWf49obyE) (I am forced to refer to external links, as the output of the system is a messy and wouldn't fit here) that you can save in a file and import with `Get`. Using `Solve` just takes `0.46` seconds, while `Reduce` takes more than `1`minute (then, I aborted the command).

How can I speed up the execution time of `Reduce` in a clever way, when dealing with a lot of variables? I guess that a system of homogenous equations in 8580 unknowns is challenging to solve. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

I have constructed an explicit example that anyone can run on his/her laptop.

```
f1[a_, b_] := Det[{\[Lambda][a], \[Lambda][b]}]
generate\[Lambda][] := Module[{},
Clear[\[Lambda]];
\[Lambda][a_] :=  \[Lambda][a] = 1/RandomInteger[{1, 4}] RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, 2];
Table[\[Lambda][a], {a, 1, 5}];]

func = Sum[Subscript[A, i, j, k, m, n, p] f[i, j] f[k, m] f[n, p], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}, {p, 1, 5}];

sys = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 250, i++,
generate\[Lambda][];
AppendTo[sys, (func /. f -> f1)==0]]
```

The function `func` generate the equations of 8000 variables, which are stored in `sys`. The variables $A_{i,j,k,m,n,p}$ are the unknowns in terms of which I want to solve the system. For the system I generate, I get a 601486920 bytes system from `ByteCount[sys]`. What is the most efficient way to get a solution of this system?

Comment: "homogeneous equations with 8580 variables" That's something you are supposed to pack into a matrix and to run `Nullspace` on it. (Hopefully the coefficients of your system are floating point numbers.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `Nullaspace` does not seems to be effecient even for one equation, you can check it with the equation posted in https://privatebin.net/?60031033c3bd109d#5edCMcmQUK9qWXVyFu3su7Y22zsGsGme2orcWf49obyE

Comment: Do you require exact solutions of your homogeneous equations or does machine precision suffice for you?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I really would like exact solutions. Then, if that's too computationally expensive, I can be happy with machine precision. Notice that If I export 261 equation in a text file, then I store more the 180MB of memory, you can download an example of such equations  here https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8at3zu3h5074o8/system.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Just too long for a comment.*

This matrix encodes 261 homogeneous equations in 8580 variables.

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {261, 8580}];
```

Its size is

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[N@ByteCount[A], "Byte"], "Megabytes"]
```

> Quantity[17.9152, "Megabytes"]

Determining a basis for its nullspace:

```
nullspace = NullSpace[A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.72552

Takes 1.7  seconds. For *all* equations at once.

## Edit

*Towards OP's edit that brought up the code for generating such a system of equations.*

I am sorry to say this, but this is really one of the worst written pieces of code that I have ever seen. It took me more than 37 GB to run it. Actually I stopped it after 10 minutes or so because I had no hope that it will terminate in the near future.

There are several things that are done in a very wrong way. Most notably:

- Using `AppendTo` for building the list `sys` where `Table` would have been entirely sufficient: Each time you append, the whole list has to be **copied** -- and because there is so large data in it, it takes forever.
- Creating aboundant, large symbolic expressions like in `func` and to use `ReplaceAll` on it hundreds of times.
- Recomputing numbers over and over again (the results of `f[i,j]` can be recycled!).

On the other hand, the **coefficient matrix** `A` of your homogeneous system can be computed in machine precision as follows within 10 ms (**milliseconds**):

First we need a `CompiledFunction` for the numbercrunching:

```
cf = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{λ, _Real, 2}},
    Block[{f, mm},
     mm = Length[λ];
     f = Table[λ[[i, 1]] λ[[j, 2]] - λ[[i, 2]] λ[[j, 1]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, 1, mm}];
     Flatten@Table[
       f[[i, j]] f[[k, m]] f[[n, p]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, 1, mm}, {k, 1, mm}, {m, 1, mm}, {n, 1, mm}, {p, 1, mm}
       ]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Next, we generate all random `λ` at once and feed them to `cf`:

```
A = cf[
     Divide[
      N[RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {250, 5, 2}]],
      N[RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {250, 5}]]
      ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.009569

Now we can compute the nullspace:

```
nullspace = NullSpace[A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 4.10173

Takes only about 4 seconds.

So, if it is about efficiency, one has also to think about efficient storage formats for the equations. And machine precision matrices are the canonical way of storing linear equations.

Comment: Thanks.. however this does not work so easily for my case.. try to download the system of equations I have uploaded here https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8at3zu3h5074o8/system.dat?dl=0 it takes too much time.

Comment: The point I wanted to make: **You stored your system in a really, really inefficient way.** I do not even know how to retrieve that data from file! And honestly, I have not time to find it out. The data is not stored as a valid _Mathematica_ expression!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used the most naive command `Export` to export the system of equations. Maybe it is not the most efficient way, but I thought it was the most obvious one.

Comment: For my system, `ByteCount` returns `9.55074*10^8` which is preatty huge.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding an explicit example that you can reproduce without downloading my file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit! This is very useful. I have never had to deal with such big expressions, I use Mathematica as a tool for more easy stuff. I didn't even know what  `Compile`GetElement`` and `Developer`ToPackedArray[` are, as well as `CompilationTarget` and all of the other methods of `cf`. I'll look at the Documentation.

Comment: Anyway, let me tell you that you should not fell sorry if a code is ill-written: people ask here because they need help, they want to learn more. I have never had to optimise my code, this is the first time. At the very end, none is forcing you to reply on SE, it should me more a pleasure. There are better ways to criticise.

Comment: Vote up and accepted answer.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `Part = Compile`GetElement`?

Comment: When _Mathematica_ translates the code into C, it adds certain bound checks whenever there is a read access to an array done with `Part`. The reasons is that the operation system might quit the copiled library **and the _Mathematica_ kernel as its parent process** whenever it tries to read out of scope of the arrays (if it is a good operating system).  So this is a robustness (and security) measure. But if one knows a priorily that the indexing does not go out of bounds, these checks just waste time.

Comment: One can deactivate the checks by using ``Compile`GetElement`` along with the option `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`. Be careful though: This can lead to runtime errors that are incredibly hard to debug, in particular if you have complex programs with many calls to compiled libraries. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174558) for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. What if instead the index of `Table` in your code run e.g. as  `Flatten@Table[
       f[[i, j]] f[[k, m]] f[[n, p]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, i, mm}, {k, 1, mm}, {m, k, mm}, {n, 1, mm}, {p, n, mm}]` ? I get the error `Compiled expression ... should be a machine-size real number`. I think it is not allowed to compile such function, am I right? What are the solution?

Comment: The problem here is that the `Table` produces a _ragged_ list and not a rectangular arrays. `Compile` cannot deal with ragged lists.