# How to efficiently solve a large system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, system-performance

This question is a follow-up of my [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202610/long-execution-time-of-reduce).

## Summary

The user Henrik Schumacher gave an excellent answer about how to store equations efficiently and solve the associated homogeneous system by using `Nullspace`. Here, I write again his code. The function `cf` generate the matrix of coefficients of the linear equations

```
cf = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{λ, _Real, 2}},
    Block[{f, mm},
     mm = Length[λ];
     f = Table[λ[[i, 1]] λ[[j, 2]] - λ[[i, 2]] λ[[j, 1]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, 1, mm}];
     Flatten@Table[
       f[[i, j]] f[[k, m]] f[[n, p]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, 1, mm}, {k, 1, mm}, {m, 1, mm}, {n, 1, mm}, {p, 1, mm}
       ]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

You can then generate 250 equations in one shoot in only 30ms

```
A = cf[
     Divide[
      Developer`ToPackedArray[
       N[RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {250, 5, 2}]]],
      Developer`ToPackedArray[N[RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {250, 5}]]]
      ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.03101

Now we can solve the system numerically with `NullSpace` in only 7 seconds

```
nullspace = NullSpace[A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 7.59116

## Question

I find the method suggested by Henrik Schumacher very useful but I am wondering whether I can improve it more. Indeed, the quantity `f` defined in the body of the function `cf` is a two rank tensor, anti-symmetric in its indexes. So, in the `Table` output there a lot of redundant terms. For example, for `mm=5`, the code generates a matrix with $5^6=15625$ entries. If you consider that `f` is a rank-2 anti-symmetric matrix in 5 dimension, then only $(10)^3 = 1000$ terms should be computed, which would be a good achievement.

I would like to use the symmetry property of `f` to further improve the code and speed up the whole process. Indeed, if you only add an extra factor of `f[[y,u]]` in the `Table` inside `cf`, i.e.

```
     Flatten@Table[
       f[[i, j]] f[[k, m]] f[[n, p]]f[[y,u]], {i, 1, mm}, {j, 1, mm}, {k, 1, mm}, {m, 1, mm}, {n, 1, mm}, {p, 1, mm},{y,1,mm},{u,1,mm}
       ]
```

then the time to generate the matrix `A` gets multiplied by a factor of 10 and Mathematica's kernel aborts when evaluating `Nullspace`.

It is even worse if I add two extra factors of `f`, in which case Mathematica takes 50 seconds to generate the matrix and i have no hope to compute the `NullSpace`.

How can I include anti-symmetry of `f` to simplify the system?